# How to define a Xpath-selector in xml schema for a recursive type

Tags: xml, xsd

Edit: added keys.

Hi,

I have a xml schema with the following types:

```
<xs:complexType name="definition">
  <xs:sequence/>
  <xs:attribute name="id"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xsd:key name="definitionId">
  <xsd:selector xpath="definition"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
</xsd:key>

<xs:complexType name="elem">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="entry1" type="elem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="entry2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This allows something like:

```
<definition id="A">
<definition id="B">
<definition id="C">

<entry1 ref="A">
  <entry1 ref="B">
    <entry1 ref="C"/>
    <entry2/>
  </entry1>
  <entry1 ref="C">
  </entry1>
</entry1>
```

I need a a XPath-selector to declare a keyref to the `ref` attribute but i don't have a clue how to define a recursive path.

```
<xsd:keyref name="definitionRef" refer="definitionId">
  <xsd:selector xpath="???"/>  <<<how to find all "ref" of entry1 ?    
  <xsd:field xpath="@ref"/>
</xsd:keyref>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For waht purpose do you need the keyref? The semantics is important.

Comment: I'm defining some elements with a id-attribute. The id-attribute is declared as a key. I want to guarantee that the content of the ref-attribute is is defined in a id-attribute. Do you get my intention or should i extent the example?

Comment: @kasten: The problem I see is that in your example you didn't provide the ID or KEY for the IDREF.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `all "ref" of entry1`? Wouldn't `//entry1/@ref` just work?

Comment: // is not part of the xpath subset supported by xml-schema. And i'm searching for an equivalent way to do this :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<xsd:selector>` supports restricted XPath expressions. Only `child` axis is allowed but the XPath expression can **begin** with `.//` so you can use a recursive expression `.//entry1`

For more detailed info, see the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#c-selector-xpath

The `<xsd:selector>` element contains an XML Path Language (XPath) expression specifying the set of elements across which the values specified by field must be unique so it shouldn't refer to attribute `ref`. `<xsd:field>` element(s) refer to the values that should be unique within that set so it should refer to attribute `ref` (and rest of the `fields` to other values, if you need to have an unique combination of values).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this for some time before my Question but missed the leading ".". Thanks for your help