# Xml schema uniqueness in entire subtree

Tags: xml, xsd

Hey guys I have a tricky problem that I can't see to solve.
I'm trying to validate unique attribute values in all descendant nodes. Not even sure this is possible given the limited xpath subset but I though I would ask.

Here's an example of what I am trying to acheive. The following XML snippet should fail to validate.

```
<Example>
  <Element1>
    <InChargeOf>
      <Element2/>
      <Element3/>
    </InChargeOf>
  </Element1>
  <Element2/>
</Example>
```

This should fail to validate due to the Element2 being both in the InChargeOf Element and the Example element.

I have tried to achieve this by assigning attributes to both the Example child element Element# and the InChargeOf child element Element# that represent the Element number as a fixed value. I think the problem comes in applying the unique selector tag as I can't seem to select all descendant nodes of the current element.

Is this possible? Any other avenues to achieve the same affect?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I found this question shortly after my post [STACK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968278/how-to-define-a-xpath-selector-in-xml-schema-for-a-recursive-type) I'm currently playing with this, no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone finding this question will want to refer to this answered identical question.
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968278/how-to-define-a-xpath-selector-in-xml-schema-for-a-recursive-type)